# How to loop through a bash array, excluding certain initial elements?

Tags: bash, shell

If I have an array:

```
declare -a arr=("element1" "element2" "element3" "element4" "element5" "element6")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

and only wanted to loop through the `element3` to `element 6`, how can I specify that? Generally, if I wanted to exclude the first `k` elements of an array, is there a way to subset that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
for i in "${arr[@]:2}"
```

Per the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), the general syntax is:

> ```
> ${parameter:offset}
> ${parameter:offset:length}
> ```
>
> ...If *parameter* is an indexed array name subscripted by `@` or `*`, the result is the *length* members of the array beginning with `${parameter[offset]}`.